# Mutate multiple / consecutive columns (with dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to learn dplyr package and so far so good. I have ran into a problem here and it definitely something to do with the syntax because its pretty easy to solve

My data frame is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H2Vb.png)

I want to add all the orders per ITEM # from fourth column on wards (from column 4 to 17)

The column should be like this

ITEM#  Total Number of Orders

1         2396

1         2396

2         445

2         445

```
  group_by(`ITEM`) %>%
  do({
  distinct(`DESCRIPTION`);
  mutate(Total = rowSums(.[,4:17]))
  })

This is definitely wrong as it says Description not found. Any help is appreciated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are using `rowSums`, it can be used directly within `mutate`.  Also, as this is doing the sum on each row, the `group_by`, is not needed.  The `distinct` part without `.keep_all = TRUE` returns only the distinct rows of 'DESCRIPTION' column.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%

      mutate(Total = rowSums(.[4:17], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
      group_by(`ITEM#`) %>%
      mutate(Total = sum(Total, na.rm = TRUE))
```

NOTE: By checking the 'DESCRIPTION' from the image, all the elements are unique, so `distinct` is not needed

Comment: So the reason why i wanted to group by was to add all the values in [4:17] for each ITEM# so for e.g. in my case for ITEM# 1 it would add the rows that have a ITEM#1 from column 4 to 17.

Comment: @Piccinin1992 I think in that case, you can do a `group_by` aftetr the `mutate` and then get the `sum` (updated)